# Drilldown packed bubble chart to scatter plot not rendering in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, scatter-plot, react-highcharts

I have a packed bubble chart, and I want to drill down the bubbles to a scatter plot. Also as a bonus would love to be able to drill down the main bubble to a scatter plot which is a mix of all of the scatter plots, I am not sure if that is possible.

I am building this code using React. Right now. On drill down, the scatter plot is not rendering.

My code: `component.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import ScatterChart from "./scatter";
import "./App.css";

const ScatterComponent = ({ data, filteredData }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const chartData = filteredData.length !== 0 ? filteredData : data;

  const bubbleSeries = [{"name":"ABC","data":[{"name":"page_views","value":6652301,
  "drilldown":"ABC - page_views"},{"name":"article_views","value":4812992,"drilldown":"ABC - article_views"},
  {"name":"visits","value":5116176,"drilldown":"ABC - visits"},]},
  {"name":"XYZ","data":[{"name":"page_views","value":16448241,"drilldown":"XYZ - page_views"},
  {"name":"article_views","value":10791478,"drilldown":"XYZ - article_views"},
  {"name":"visits","value":11921915,"drilldown":"XYZ - visits"},]}];

  const scatterSeries = [{"type":"scatter","id":"ABC - page_views",
  "data":[["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",1]],},
  {"type":"scatter","id":"ABC - article_views",
  "data":[["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",1]],},
  {"type":"scatter","id":"ABC - visits",
  "data":[["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",1]],},
  {"type":"scatter","id":"XYZ - page_views",
  "data":[["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",1]],},
  {"type":"scatter","id":"XYZ - article_views",
  "data":[["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",1]],},
  {"type":"scatter","id":"XYZ - visits",
  "data":[["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",1],["2024-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",1]],},
]
  


  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(delay);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bubbleScatterTrends clearfix w-100 column">
      <h3 className="mt-1 ms-1" style={{ color: "#81b0d2" }}>
        <u>ABC-XYZ Breakdowns</u>
      </h3>
      {loading ? (
        <div className="text-center">
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="secondary" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="success" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="danger" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="warning" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="info" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="light" />
          <Spinner animation="border" variant="dark" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="clearfix w-100 column">
          <div className="clearfix w-100 column">
            <div className="w-100 bubbleScatterCharts">
              <ScatterChart
                bubbleData={bubbleSeries}
                scatterData={scatterSeries}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScatterComponent;
```

`scatter.js`

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import highchartsAccessibility from "highcharts/modules/accessibility";
import highchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import highchartsExportData from "highcharts/modules/export-data";
import highchartsPackedbubble from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import "dayjs/locale/es";

highchartsAccessibility(Highcharts);
highchartsExporting(Highcharts);
highchartsExportData(Highcharts);
highchartsPackedbubble(Highcharts);

const ScatterChart = ({ bubbleData, scatterData }) => {
  dayjs.locale("en");
  const addCommas = (x) =>
    x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

  const options = useMemo(
    () => ({
      chart: {
        type: "packedbubble",
        backgroundColor: "#283347",
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
          verticalAlign: "top",
          y: -10,
          x: -5,
        },
      },
      accessibility: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true,
        itemStyle: {
          color: "#fff",
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: "#283347",
        style: { color: "#fff" },
        formatter: function () {
          if (this.y !== undefined || this.key !== undefined) {
            let tooltip = `<span><b><u>${this.key}</u></b>: ${addCommas(
              this.y
            )}</span>`;
            return tooltip;
          }
        },
        useHTML: true,
      },
      plotOptions: {
        packedbubble: {
          minSize: "20%",
          maxSize: "100%",
          zMin: 0,
          zMax: 1000,
          layoutAlgorithm: {
            gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
            splitSeries: true,
            seriesInteraction: false,
            dragBetweenSeries: true,
            parentNodeLimit: true,
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: "{point.name}",
            filter: {
              property: "y",
              operator: ">",
              value: 250,
            },
            style: {
              color: "black",
              textOutline: "none",
              fontWeight: "normal",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      series: bubbleData,
      drilldown: {
        series: scatterData,
      },
    }),
    [bubbleData, scatterData]
  );

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};

export default ScatterChart;
```

My scatter plot is not rendering.

[image: scatterplot]

Answer (score 0):

I created a packedbubble demo with drilldown to scatter plot in React. Please take a look at it and let me know if you have any further questions.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-16gsxb?file=style.css,index.js